# Lang text with control panel interface

Tags: add-on-development, module, plugin, extension

On a new project, the client requires that it be possible to add/modify all text.

I will be using channel entries to hold majority of the 'content' text, but I am more perplexed by how I should allow text editing for hard coded items, like button text, headers, navigation etc.

Ideally, I would like to be able to code variables into the templates without any wrapping tags. Essentially like a global variable. For example:

```
<input type="submit" val="{lang_login_btn}" />
```

`{lang_login_btn}` being the variable.

The text all needs to be manageable by the client, so there has to be some kind of control panel interface, or at the very least a 'lang' document.

What would you recommend for this?

A custom module? If so, is it possible to have a module that can output variables like this without the use of wrapping tags?

I have built many plugins and extensions, but only basic modules without control panel interface.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use built-in Global Variables feature or [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) add-on

Both will work same way, you'll just place {variable_name} in your templates, without any other special tags, but you may find Low Variables interface easier to manage variables, as they all are presented on same page.